# Cluster word2vec vectors using Affinity Propagation in python (sklearn)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, text-mining, word2vec

I want to cluster my word2vec clusters using Affinity Propagation and get the cluster center words.

My current code is as follows.

```
model = word2vec.Word2Vec.load("word2vec")
word_vectors = model.wv.syn0
affprop = AffinityPropagation(affinity="precomputed", damping=0.5)
af= affprop.fit(word_vectors)
```

However, this raise the following error:
`ValueError: S must be a square array (shape=(77, 300))`

As I understand 300 means word2vec hidden layer dimension and 77 is my vocabulary size.

I am just wondering how to use Affinity Propagation for word2vec vectors that are not square arrays.

Please help me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you stated that the affinity between samples is already computed, which is always a square matrix. So you can either use Euclidean distance which is implemented, or if you want to use a different metric you have to precompute it, see the example code below:

```
# some dummy data
word_vectors = np.random.random((77, 300))

# using eucliden distance
affprop = AffinityPropagation(affinity='euclidean', damping=0.5)
af = affprop.fit(word_vectors)

# using cosine
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_distances
word_cosine = cosine_distances(word_vectors)
affprop = AffinityPropagation(affinity='precomputed', damping=0.5)
af = affprop.fit(word_cosine)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great answer :) Can we directly calculate cosine distance as you have mentioned or do we need to use methods like this: `index = gensim.similarities.MatrixSimilarity(gensim.matutils.Dense2Corpus(word_vectors))

for sims in index:
    similarity_matrix.append(sims)
similarity_array = np.array(similarity_matrix)`

Comment: You can calculate the distances using any method you want. I tend to use scikit for simplicity.

Comment: Can you please let me know if the matrix that we input to affinity propagation essentially need to be a distance matrix? Can we input a similarity matrix instead? :)

Comment: It **should** be a similarity matrix. Sorry there was ambiguity in my last comment, basically scikit uses negative Euclidean distances so that larger values indicate values are closer.